# Pooled time series

Tags: time-series, clustering, pooling

Can somebody tell me

1. what are and how to do **pooled time series**?
2. and in what way it can help me to **build forecast models from clusters of time series?**

Maharaj and Brett do this in their article http://ideas.repec.org/p/msh/ebswps/1999-9.html

Thanks.

Comment: The paper you link to seems to answer your questions. Perhaps you can rephrase your question to ask something specific in the paper that you did not understand?

Comment: @DarrenCook is just as simple as, if I have 3 series with length of 5 such as:
Y1'= [1,3,5,7,10]
Y2'= [4,6,7,3,9]
Y3'= [2,8,1,5,8]

To pool the series is simply:
Yp=[1,3,5,7,10,4,6,7,3,9,2,8,1,5,8]
Is it this?